# Two TYPO3 globalVar are the same

Tags: conditional-statements, typo3, typoscript

I have this condition in TypoScript:

```
[globalVar = TSFE:fe_user|sesData|get_car = TSFE:fe_user|sesData|return_car]
   # Do nothing 
[else]
   plugin.Tx_Formhandler.settings.predef.formhandler-multistep-forms-rent-a-car {
      markers.master_input_price_out_town1 = TEXT
      markers.master_input_price_out_town1.value = Zwrot samochodu:

      markers.master_input_price_out_town2 = CONTENT
      markers.master_input_price_out_town2 {
        table = tx_pricelist_additional_price
        select {
          pidInList = 44
          orderBy = uid
          selectFields = uid, return_another_department
          # possible conditions
           where = ( hidden='0' AND deleted='0')
        } 
        renderObj = COA
        renderObj {
          #value  
          1 = TEXT
          1.insertData = 1 
          1.data = field: return_another_department      
          1.stdWrap.prioriCalc = 1
          1.wrap = <div>|</div>
        }
      }
   }
[global]
```

Because in TS there is no such think like `!=` I use `[else]` condition, but the `CODE` is executed even when `get_car` and `return_car` are the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you cannot have dynamic value as the second argument (that is after the operator "="). In other words it probably can be only "statitc" string, optionally with a wildcard (*).

Answer (score 1):

TypoScript shouldn't be considered as advanced programming language, so trying to prepare more and more sophisticated conditions will lead you soon to the dead end.

Although you didn't specify what the `CODE`s task is, I could advice to consider writing custom extension,anyway if it's not required you'll make better deal writing at least custom condition in `localconf.php` using `userFunc` so you can use much more sophisticated operators, [check the doc, at bottom](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.7.0/view/1/4/).

Comment: I wouldn't consider using extension for this as it would be in my opinion an overkill. The custom function placed in `localconf.php` is a good solution so my +1 for that.

Comment: @cascaval, de facto it was just advice, as I wrote I don't know what the CODE means... However, each TYPO3 instantion should have small `general` extension, where developer can put his small pieces of PHP instead wasting hours to realize that `TypoScript` is not a programming language (neither its simulations) that's just a configuration array

Comment: Biesior - I pastle whole code - it is for Formhandler extension

Comment: @Adrian as cascaval wrote, in this case it's enough to use `userFunc` as a condition as you just need to reconfigure formhandler

Comment: @biesior, I agree with you that TypoScript is not a programming language and thus not suitable for some advanced stuff. I only meant that it seems to me unnecessary to write an extension when one function placed in the localconf.php would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I made this in some other way:

```
[globalString = TSFE:fe_user|sesData|get_car = *] && [globalString = TSFE:fe_user|sesData|return_car = *] 
   CODE
[global]
```

and

```
[globalVar = TSFE:fe_user|sesData|get_car = City] && [globalVar = TSFE:fe_user|sesData|return_car = City] 
   CODE for "Do nothing"
[global]
```

Thanks for any advice!